# Unable to delete selected item using backspace in v-autocomplete with custom item template in Vue.js

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

`I'm using the "v-autocomplete" component from the Vuetify UI library in a Vue.js application to implement an autocomplete input field. The "v-autocomplete" component is connected to an Dummy API that returns a list of users. Each user object contains a 'first Name' And "last Name" property, and I'm using a custom template to display them together as a single item separated by comma in the suggestion list(ex:- John, Smith ).

The issue I'm facing is that after selecting an item from the suggestion list, I'm unable to delete it using the backspace key. Additionally, when I type in the input field, the text I enter is combined with the selected item, which is not what I want.

Note that the "clearable" prop is not a solution for me, as I specifically want to be able to delete the selected item using the backspace key.

Here's a Code Pen with the relevant part of my code:https://codepen.io/Sumithra-Annegowda/pen/LYgOEam

How can I fix this issue so that I'm able to delete selected items using the backspace key and prevent the input field from combining my text with the selected item? I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions.

Background:
My actual requirement is to create a AutoComplete box `your text`where the user enters the area name and I need to suggest the address based on user input. My API will filter the suggestions in the backend using here maps API. 
I created this Code Pen using dummy API to replicate my scenario.
`